# Creating a virtual adapter and running all traffic through SOCKS5 / SSH (Debian)

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, proxy, socks

I have a Digital Ocean VPS running a Winodws VM (VirtualBox) that I want to only route traffic through a single Socks5 that I change daily ... The only way to do this is(it seems) is to bridge the VM into a virtual adapter and have that virtual adapter routed through a remote Socks5.

Im a unix noob and have no idea how to use do this correctly, I have seen this done with TOR at questions/330/running-a-virtual-machine-vm-that-can-only-connect-through-tor/376 but I'm not interested in TOR and I can barely figure out how to create a virtual adapter correctly .... Do I need some type of SSH tunnel to the Socks5 mapped to a virtual adapter and then make a bridge with "brctl" ?

I created a virtual adapter "Br0" as below and tried with connect-proxy but couldn;t get it to work.

````
```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::30a0:95ff:fe59:381f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 32:a0:95:59:38:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 162  bytes 26949 (26.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 165.22.37.x  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 165.22.47.255
        inet6 fe80::7455:51ff:fe61:ccd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2604:a880:800:c1::193:f001  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 76:55:51:61:0c:cd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14072  bytes 1273849 (1.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30801  bytes 6612660 (6.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.17.0.x  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.17.255.255
        ether 76:55:51:61:0c:cd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 17226  bytes 5385950 (5.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17226  bytes 5385950 (5.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```
````

Comment: See e.g. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/469094/how-to-create-a-virtual-interface-from-a-socks-proxy). You do that **inside** the VM, and set the default route on the new `tun` interface. No need to "bridge the VM into a virtual adapter". Depending on you mean by VPS, if it's a single application, you can also make this application use a Socks proxy **inside** the VM.

Comment: I'm running a Windows VM (VirtualBox) on a Digital Ocean VPS .... Any SOCKS proxying inside the VM still leaks WEBRTC and such, the only way to do it with VB is to bridge to something like a virtual adapter.

Comment: @A.B That would be redirecting all on the host no?

Comment: @Hoorah you're probably right. I removed my suggestions

Comment: I think it could be useful all traffic would be a last resort, theres also something called  [Brook](https://github.com/txthinking/brook) but setting it up looks challenging.